# How to read specific lines from a file?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to read data from a text file in the format below. How can I skip reading any lines that begin with an asterisk ?

```
* Data set 34.6
* Author: M. S.
1   3     
6   7     
4   5     
... so on
```

The relevant part of my code currently looks like this.. It can read and insert 2 numbers to my set at a time but I get errors if there are comment lines on top starting with asterisk. So I'm not sure how I would ignore those lines while the file is being read.

```
string lin;
while (getline(if1, lin)) {
        istringstream is1(lin);
        int a, b;
        if (is >> a >> b) {
            set3.insert({a, b});                                    
        } 
    }
```

Comment: *it can read and insert 2 numbers to my set at a time* It looks like you're reading and inserting 3...

Comment: The short answer is that you can't avoid reading them. About all you can do is read them, check if they start with an asterisk, and if so just go on to the next line without storing them. If you're going to reread the same file more than once, you can build an index showing where each line starts, and seek to the beginning of the next line when you find an asterisk (but you probably won't gain much by doing so).

Comment: Try `if(!lin.empty() && lin[0] != '*')`. FYI `lin[0]` is the first character of `lin`.

Comment: @Josh yea sorry, I changed that. Its supposed to read two numbers only at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the asterisk before you do any more reading, and if you find it, `continue` (jump to the next iteration of the `while`):

```
string lin;
while (getline(if1, lin)) {
    if(lin[0] == '*') continue; //Skip this line if it's bad
    istringstream is1(lin);
    int a, b;
    if (is >> a >> b) {
        set3.insert({a, b});                                    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your file has specific format (for example every line that starts with asterisk has fixed amount of symbols in it) you cannot skip that line, as you do not know how many symbols to skip. What you probably should do - read file line by line, and if line that you read starts with asterisk skip processing it.

```
string lin;
while (getline(if1, lin)) {
    if( lin.length() == 0 || lin[0] == '*' ) continue;
    istringstream is1(lin);
    int a, b;
    if (is1 >> a >> b) {
        set3.insert({a, b});                                    
    } 
}
```